# Is there a simple way to append a byte to a StringBuffer and specify the encoding?

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, char, byte

### Question

What is the simplest way to append a byte to a StringBuffer (i.e. cast a byte to a char) and specify the character encoding used (ASCII, UTF-8, etc)?

### Context

I want to append a byte to a stringbuffer. Doing so requires casting the byte to a char:

```
myStringBuffer.append((char)nextByte);
```

However, the code above uses the default character encoding for my machine (which is MacRoman).  Meanwhile, other components in the system/network require UTF-8.  So I need to so something like:

```
try {
    myStringBuffer.append(new String(new Byte[]{nextByte}, "UTF-8"));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    //handle error
}
```

Which, frankly, is pretty ugly.

Surely, there's a better way (other than breaking the same code into multiple lines)???????

Comment: Slightly off topic, in Java 5+ use a `StringBuilder` in lieu of `StringBuffer`s. Unless you know why you need a `StringBuffer` (internally synchronized), then you don't need it compared to a `StringBuilder`, which is identical in operation and methods, but it's just always faster.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The simple answer is 'no'. What if the byte is the first byte of a multi-byte sequence? Nothing would maintain the state.

If you have all the bytes of a logical character in hand, you can do:

```
sb.append(new String(bytes, charset));
```

But if you have one byte of UTF-8, you can't do this at all with stock classes.

It would not be terribly difficult to build a juiced-up StringBuffer that uses java.nio.charset classes to implement byte appending, but it would not be one or two lines of code.

Comments indicate that there's some basic Unicode knowledge needed here.

In UTF-8, 'a' is one byte, 'á' is two bytes, '丧' is three bytes, and '' is four bytes. The job of [CharsetDecoder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) is to convert these sequences into Unicode characters. Viewed as a sequential operation over bytes, this is obviously a stateful process.

If you create a `CharsetDecoder` for UTF-8, you can feed it only byte at a time (in a `ByteBuffer`) via [this method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html#decode%28java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20java.nio.CharBuffer,%20boolean%29). The UTF-16 characters will accumulate in the output `CharBuffer`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're saying regarding issues with a 'multi-byte' sequence.  I have a series of UTF-8 characters coming in as bytes, I constantly append them to a string buffer (one-by-one). I need to cast the bytes into UTF-8 characters but doing so is ugly.

Comment: perhaps the confusion comes from these actually being ASCII characters that I'm casting to UTF-8. I don't know much about UTF-8, does it span multiple bytes?

Comment: Yes.  ASCII characters are represented by single bytes, and non-ASCII characters are represented by 2, 3, or 4 bytes.

Comment: If they are just ASCII, then you should use a helper method that simply catches the exception. `public static String bytesToUsAscii(byte[] bytes) { try { return new String(bytes, "US-ASCII"); } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { throw new IllegalStateException(e); } }`. The JVM guarantees that US-ASCII is a supported character encoding (as well as UTF-8 and UTF-16), so the exception will never occur unless something is seriously wrong.

Comment: @pic @dan Without stronger evidence, I'm unwilling to assume that the OP is really dealing with ISO-646. He or she explicitly mentions UTF-8 as opposed to ASCII.

Comment: @bmargulies The OP mentions that it's actually ASCII in the second comment of this answer.

Comment: @pick then read his second sentence and see if you wobble like I do.

Comment: @bmargulies I understand the fear, and even agree with it. However, he claimed to know that it was ASCII and, without any other evidence, I  only assume that his UTF-8 comments were simply out of ignorance of the subject.

Comment: @bmargulies/pickypg: thanks guys.  The simple answer is "no" there is no easier way around this. I was able to get a guarantee that we are only ever dealing with ASCII. So I changed all UTF-8 references over to ASCII; however, the process still involves this awkward syntax as well as a pointless try/catch for an error that is certain to never happen. So I just softened/crosscut it with an aspect and called it a day!

Answer (score 4):

I think the error here is in dealing with bytes at all. You want to deal with strings of characters instead.

Just interpose a reader on the input and output stream to do the mapping between bytes and characters for you. Use the `InputStreamReader(InputStream in, CharsetDecoder dec)` form of the constructor for the input, though, so that you can detect input encoding errors via an exception. Now you have strings of characters instead of buffers of bytes.  Put an `OutputStreamWriter` on the other end.

Now you no longer have to worry about bytes or encodings. It’s much simpler this way.